# Is there a Java library for processing ONIX files?

Tags: java

I've had a search around, but I couldn't find any java libraries to process ONIX files.

I guess there is always the option of processing the XML directly, but I thought I'd check to see if there was any libraries available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the **Jonix library** at https://github.com/zach-m/jonix.

It's fast, effective, accurate and very easy to tweak.

Also, it's actively maintained to always reflect the latest version of ONIX.

Comment: and best of all, it's maintained by you! ;-)

Comment: Proudly so.. and in use by 100s of users so far. Jonix 3 is fully supporting ONIX 3 now.

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you're looking for? https://code.google.com/p/onixj/ From the blurb:

"Fast XML - Java object mapping for reading and writing EDItEUR Onix XML files, optimized for memory usage, model navigation and speed. The project offers an Java API to access and manipulate Onix data."

Comment: Project seems dead. they haven't released any code since inception on march 3 2010.

Comment: Check https://github.com/zach-m/jonix